# How do I pay for something anonymously from the UK using bitcoins?

Tags: privacy, tor, bitinstant

I've seen the following guide but it's no good as I can't use bitinstant from the UK. Can someone recommend an alternative?

Step 1.
Download and install TOR

Step 2. 
While using TOR create a Tormail account 
You can confirm the address at http://tormail.org/

Step 3. 
While using TOR, visit http://www.bitinstant.com

Step 4.
Choose the Cash deposit to Bitcoin to email option.

Step 5.
Follow the instructions on Bitinstant to make your cash deposit, and have your Bitcoins sent to your new Tormail account.
No ID is needed.

Step 6.
Receive your Bitcoins via email.

Comment: Is the question only about "how do I purchase bitcoins anonymously from the UK"?

Answer (score 2):

Buying coins non-anonymously in the UK:
Transferwise to Bitstamp's European account - £1 transfer fee, then <0.5% commission to buy.

Spending:
I guess you would use a mixer service

Comment: Transferwise no longer supports withdrawing to Bitcoin exchanges.  You can still use CurrencyFair though.

Answer (score 0):

You can deposit cash into Mt. Gox's account with Barclays but you can't use Tor to set that up as Mt. Gox will insist on you providing identity to access your funds after your account first is accessed through Tor.

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mtgox#UK_.28GBP.29

There is a site called London Bitcoin Exchange, though there is not much about them yet but perhaps you can trade in-person.

- http://londonbitcoinexchange.wordpress.com/

You can send cash (GBP) or check to Bitcoin Nordic, by mail, to purchase bitcoins:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Nordic  (They accept other currencies, like EUR, as well.)

You might find a local trader (or place an buy order and see if anyone is selling):

- http://www.LocalBitcoins.com

There are a number of methods:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins

[Update: You can also buy bitcoins from the UK now using BlockChain.info/wallet thanks to their integration with Barclay's Pingit:

- https://blockchain.info/wallet/deposit-pingit

Or even better, using "Faster Payments" bank transfer:

- http://blockchain.info/wallet/deposit-bank-transfer ]

[Update2: Tenakha does many [person-to-person trades](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=108712.0) in London.]

Comment: And one other, temporary, option -- you can meet with the folks  as the London Bitcoin Conference:

 - http://www.bitcoin2012.com
 - http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=67199.0

Answer (score 0):

Buying bitcoins is location dependent.

Paying for a purchase using bitcoins is not location dependent, you can do that from anywhere in the world.

There are mixing services that will help protect the privacy of your payment.

Blockchain.info/wallet provides the ability to send a payment through a mixing service.

So after you've acquired bitcoins in whatever manner suitable in your location, then send them to your wallet on Blockchain.info/wallet.

You can access that wallet using Tor.

- http://Blockchain.info/wallet